# Hashtable as JSON from Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx, hashtable

I'm trying to return a list of key/value pairs as JSON from a web service but getting a serialization error with Hashtable.

I've used this in other projects and it was working with returning a Hashtable yesterday, however, it would seem something has changed which causes an error to be thrown:

> The type System.Collections.Hashtable
>   is not supported because it implements
>   IDictionary.

I've worked around this by using List>, but I don't see why this was previously working and now is not.

My method signature is:

```
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
[WebMethod]
public List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> FindPosts(string type, string searchText, int offset) {
```

Comment: How did you get from a Hashtable to JSON before?  Are you using the .NET native JSON? (I usually use JSON.NET.)

Comment: Are you using the JavaScriptSerializer class? The Docs indicate that serialization of Hashtable is supported....
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

Comment: I'm using th built in .NET serialization.

Answer (score 2):

Internal Json serializer is perfectly capable of serializing/deserializing hashtable where Xml serializer is not so you're probably using Xml serializer somewhere in your code without noticing it. Look through your code to make sure that all serializations use Json.